# PerformanceAnalytics Error t(w) %*% M3 : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

On R version 2.15.2, while using the ES function in PerformanceAnalytics:

```
ES(R=indexes, weights=w)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in t(w) %*% M3 : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

where w is

```
      [,1]
[1,]  0.5
[2,]  0.5
```

both is.matrix(w) and is.numeric(w) return TRUE

Calling the function without passing weights (i.e. ES(R=indexes) ) works.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The doc says `weights` is a vector, so try `weights = c(w)`. If it still does not work, please provide `str(indexes)` and `str(w)`. Or make your error reproducible by giving us data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this edhec data (given with package) and the weights vector I can reproduce the error ( Please give a reproducible example next time, otherwise we will not be sure to give sense to the following answer)

```
weights <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5)       ## must be to number of columns in R"
ES(R = edhec[,1:5], weights= weights)
Error in t(w) %*% M3 : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

The error because the M3 matrix is null. You need to change the argument `portfolio_method` from the default `single` to `component`. The help talk about weights in the *Component ES* part, so this make sense. Otherwise , I think you need to suplly m3,m4, mu...(painful)

Try this

```
ES(R = edhec[,1:5], weights= weights,
       portfolio_method= 'component')

$MES
          [,1]
[1,] 0.0331994

$contribution
Convertible Arbitrage            CTA Global Distressed Securities      Emerging Markets Equity Market Neutral 
          0.015504952          -0.006116166           0.004702236           0.007760899           0.011347477 

$pct_contrib_MES
Convertible Arbitrage            CTA Global Distressed Securities      Emerging Markets Equity Market Neutral 
            0.4670251            -0.1842252             0.1416362             0.2337662             0.3417977
```